# windows Service name and service status send to web api without database from app setting config file

Tags: c#

How to monitoring service every 30 sec using windows service without hard coded by service name

Comment: By config do you mean `app.config`?

Comment: Yes through config file

Comment: I'd imagine you would have to give rights to the Web Api to the folder the windows service lives in, then load the configuration using ConfigurationManager.

Comment: how to send to web those value and how to keep value in config file we cannot keep the value in config file